# Laravel 5.3 Login Routes - NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to build up my new project and i'm using Laravel 5.3. 
My problem is, that the auth routes doesn't work like expected.. I allways get the following error:

`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php`

I removed the laravel auth routes that comes with the new update :

```
Those: Auth::routes();
```

and replaced them with:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
// Login Routes...
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);

// Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm']);
    Route::post('register', ['as' => 'register.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
    Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'password.email', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'password.reset.token', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
    Route::post('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
});
```

Okay now I'm trying to use them but I allways get the mentioned exception

The url I was testing: http://localhost/project/public/login

I dont know where the "public" comes from.. thats from xampp or something like that..

So this gives me the error.

if I add this route:

`Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');` // outsite and inside of the route group

I get redirected to the Login Form and everythings fine

if I try:

`Route::get('/test', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');` // same with Route::get('test', ...)

I also get the error. Does someone have a solution for that?

Comment: oh... damn you right.. I did that and it works now.. god damnit

Comment: write a answer, I will vote it as best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run Laravel app like that. you need to run `php artisan serve command`

and then go to `localhost:8000`